# Calculus Help about Integration

Tags: calculus

I am totally stuck at this problem, I have totally no clue where to start:

$\int x(x^2-a^x) \, dx$

please help thanks

Comment: Remember that integration is a "linear operator", that is: $\int f(x) + g(x)~dx = \int f(x)~dx + \int g(x)~dx$. You can justify this with the sum rule for derivatives.

Comment: Please ignore my vote to close. The two questions looked identical from the preview on the main page!

Answer (score 3):

We have $$\int{x^3-xa^x} = \int{x^3} - \int{xa^x} = \frac{x^4}{4} - \int{xa^x}+C$$  Use integration by parts on the second integral $u=x, du = dx, dv = a^x, v=\frac{1}{\log(a)}a^x$ to get

$$=\frac{x^4}{4} - x\frac{1}{\log(a)}a^x + \frac{1}{(\log(a))^2}a^x + C$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Multiply through by $x$. The $x^3$ part is easy. For the rest, we want $\int xa^x\,dx$. We have $a^x=e^{(\ln a)x}$. Now use integration by parts.